# Why does this fish while loop terminate after a single iteration?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, fish, npm-run

This is a fish function used to upgrade JavaScript packages for a project. Strangely, it terminates after a single iteration with an exit status of 0. Why?

```
function yarn-upgrade-all --description "Upgrade JavaScript packages"
    yarn outdated | sed '1,/^Package/d;/^Done/d' | awk '{print $1, $4}' | while read -l PACKAGE VERSION
        echo
        set_color brwhite
        echo -n "==>"
        set_color yellow
        echo -n " "$PACKAGE
        set_color brblue
        echo -n " "$VERSION
        set_color brwhite
        echo -n " <=="
        set_color normal
        echo
        echo

        yarn upgrade --latest $PACKAGE
        and yarn run test
        and yarn run build
        and git commit -am "Upgrade to "$PACKAGE" "$VERSION
        or begin
            set_color red
            echo "last command exited with status $status" >&2
            set_color normal
            return 1
        end
    end
end
```

On the other hand, this second function, which contains only a stub body, runs through all packages piped into the loop.

```
function yarn-upgrade-all-debug --description "Upgrade JavaScript packages"
    yarn outdated | sed '1,/^Package/d;/^Done/d' | awk '{print $1, $4}' | while read -l PACKAGE VERSION
        echo $PACKAGE $VERSION
    end
end
```

**fish --version**

`fish, version 3.0.2`

Comment: Does one of those `yarn` commands, or the `git` command, slurp up the rest of the stdin?

Comment: @glennjackman You're right. Redirecting stdin to /dev/null for the commands in the loop body fixes it. Would you like to add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop terminates after a single iteration because the `yarn run` invocations in the loop body slurp up the rest of stdin. (Credits to [@glenn-jackman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55751619/why-does-this-fish-while-loop-terminate-after-a-single-iteration#comment98181450_55751619).)

A possible workaround is to redirect stdin to `/dev/null` for these commands:

```
        and yarn run test < /dev/null
        and yarn run build < /dev/null
```

The culprit is `run-s` from the [npm-run-all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-run-all) package, which is invoked by both `yarn run` commands.

https://github.com/mysticatea/npm-run-all/issues/166

Answer (score 2):

You're running fish 3.0.0, and hitting https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/5513 - `return` from a `while` doesn't actually set the status correctly.

However, the `return` still causes it to terminate the while-loop.

Upgrade to 3.0.2.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already running fish 3.0.2. Updated the question with the fish version.